# Error Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005' Access Databases when trying to click on links

Tags: asp.net, database, odbc, driver

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Your network access was interrupted. To continue, close the database, and then open it again.

/AGSafety/AGSafetydbconn.inc, line 5
moved databases from server 2008 to 2019 Installed IIS version 10 instead of version 6. installed access drivers for ODBC. keep getting this message. have given permissions to groups and individuals.

unable to get past this driver message no matter the permissions or any other changes I make. is it the version of the IIS?

Comment: Did you search about the error message? It seems to me that there are a lot of links and possible solutions. See this for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/your-network-access-was-interrupted-error?source=recommendations

Comment: That 800 series error suggests that your running the new IIS server as a x64 bit server. But use of "mdb" files and JET only allows you to use JET in a x32 mode. You have to thus either force the IIS to run as x32 bits (enable the x32 pool), or you can install ACE x64 bits, and use the ACE driver. The ACE driver should be able to open mdb file - but it depends on how old it it is. ACE data engine of course can open mdb or accdb files. So, best bets is to proably installed the ACE access driver - the x64 bit version.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did go to application pool and change to 32 bit still would not open where do I access the ACE drivers?